# Lidar LSC-Laser scanner c25 error and forced to close rviz

Tags: ros, ros-noetic, pointcloud-to-laserscan

I have LSC lidar laser scan with type LSC-C25. After some period running the package, I got error like this:

```
Terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Duration has to be finite.
[rviz-3] process has died [pid 3544, exit code -6, cmd /home/whitehorse/catkin_ws/devel/lib/rviz/rviz -d /home/whitehorse/catkin_ws/src/lsc_ros_driver/rviz/lsc_rviz.rviz __name:=rviz __log:=/home/whitehorse/.ros/log/561aa54a-7a03-11ee-9d1f-99890ba3c159/rviz-3.log].
log file: /home/whitehorse/.ros/log/561aa54a-7a03-11ee-9d1f-99890ba3c159/rviz-3*.log
```

The error can happen with just launch the original launcher `lsc_c25_launch.launch` with RViz view. I have no idea how to solve it. If the package running with another node/package, error messege will be like this:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Duration has to be finite.
[ WARN] [1699336825.913255856]: transformLaserScanToPointCloud error, it seems the message from laser sensor is malformed. Ignore this laser scan. what(): Duration has to be finite.
[rviz-3] process has died [pid 22271, exit code -6, cmd /home/whitehorse/catkin_ws/devel/lib/rviz/rviz -d /home/whitehorse/catkin_ws/src/mobile_robot_autonomous_navigation/config/nav_config_teb.rviz __name:=rviz __log:=/home/whitehorse/.ros/log/06709454-7d29-11ee-b031-e92b64bd451b/rviz-3.log].
log file: /home/whitehorse/.ros/log/06709454-7d29-11ee-b031-e92b64bd451b/rviz-3*.lo
```

Is any one have the same experience like this? My system is running on LattePanda 3 Delta, Ubuntu 20, ROS Noetic.